# Cannot invoke "de.slackspace.openkeepass.domain.CrsAlgorithm.ordinal()" because "algorithm" is null - KeePassXC 2.7.4 with Spring Boot - stoped work

Tags: java, maven, keepass

How I can solve this issue,

I created last year app in Java Spring Boot where this app is opening KeePass Database with passwords.

I am using on Windows OpenJDK version 17.0.5

In Maven I am importing that extension:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.slackspace/openkeepass -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.slackspace</groupId>
            <artifactId>openkeepass</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
      </dependency>
```

It worked fine till last friday, now when I am trying start app I receive this error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'alias' defined in file [C:\Users\XX\JavaProjects\CC\flow-crm-tutorial\target\classes\com\example\application\data\Alias.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.application.data.Alias]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "de.slackspace.openkeepass.domain.CrsAlgorithm.ordinal()" because "algorithm" is null
```

Temporary I solved issue when I changed in KeePass file extension from KDBX 4 in to KDBX 3

but I need fix it to work with KDBX 4

Any suggestions ?